# String Replace Java Function

Tags: java, string, class, replace, bukkit

1. I tried to Replace in multiple classes an multiple Strings with a function
2. Why does this example not Work?

   ```
   public static String symbole(String sym)
    {  
   sym = sym.replace("&" , "§");
   sym = sym.replace("[<3]" , "\u2764");
   return sym;
   }
   String test = "This Dont work... why [<3]";
   symbole(test);
   ```

how can i replace this... 
any Suggestion?
Please help and sorry for my perfect english

Comment: Works fine for me. What are you seeing?

Comment: what do you mean by " it does not work?". It works good. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Can you provide some example to string and expected replacement?

Comment: what is your output? do you see question marks? could be an encoding thing. Do you run in an IDE? or shell? operating sys? java version?

Comment: How did you test that it doesn't work? Is it possible that you forgot to use value returned by `symbole(test)` and are printing `test` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, most likely, because you expect that your function mutates the original String you passed to the method.

Strings are immutable in java, and besides, you cannot modify the original reference you pass to method from that method.

To get the result you most likely expect, store returned value from a method in a new reference, or have the test reference point to returned String.

So you can try:

```
test = symbole(test);
```

or

```
String replacedTest = symbole(test):
```

Answer (score 2):

The following statement:

```
sym.replace("[<3]", "\u2764");
```

Works and will replace `[<3]` with the "heart" character.

I imagine your problem is that you think `test` will be modified when you pass it to the method. This won't work because `String` is immutable; calling `replace` actually returns a *new* `String` instance. You cannot assign it back to `sym` and expect `test` to change since Java is pass-by-value and you cannot reseat references. However, since you're already returning the modified string, you just need to assign the return value back to `test`:

```
test = symbole(test);
```

You can also assign it to a new variable if you want:

```
String modified = symbole(test);
```